# Which protobuf optimization?

Tags: c++, optimization, protocol-buffers

Using google's protocol buffer compiler for c++ its not clear which is faster: optimize for speed:

```
option optimize_for = SPEED;
```

or optimize for light runtime:

```
option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;
```

if speed is faster, what makes it faster?
does anyone have hard data on the subject?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The way I read the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated.html#message),

- optimize for CODE_SIZE does not generate fast accessor methods for everything, but relies on slow reflection,
- optimize for SPEED will give you the fast accessors
- and optimize for LITE_RUNTIME will also give you fast accessors, but does not support the full functionality of protobuf, but only the lighter subset protobuf-lite. Basically, this means descriptors or reflection are not available.

So I guess, LITE_RUNTIME is not slower than SPEED, and you should choose depending on which runtime library you want to require (lite or full).

> if speed is faster, what makes it faster?

SPEED is faster compared to CODE_SIZE, because it uses autogenerated code instead of runtime reflection.

Comment: I understood that too ... however experimental evidence showed that SPEED was slightly faster ... ? can anyone else confirm?